# CGI script with Python - Testing browser on local server

Tags: python, windows, command-line, cgi

I am messing around trying to test a CGI Python script locally on a Windows machine..
I followed a tutorial, so it's pretty simple.  Here is my Python script (named test_cgi.py, located in a cgi-bin directory).

```
print "Content-type: text/html"
print "<html>"
print "<title>Test CGI</title>"
print "<body>"
print "<p>Hello World!</p>"
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

Here is another script that will start the server:

```
import BaseHTTPServer
import CGIHTTPServer
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()  ## This line enables CGI error reporting

server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
handler = CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler
server_address = ("", 8000)
handler.cgi_directories = [""]

httpd = server(server_address, handler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

After starting the server, when I navigate to `http://localhost:8000/test_cgi.py`, instead of the browser displaying the HTML contents, it displays the ENTIRE contents of the script.  Any ideas?

1. Yes, all my files have executable permissions.
2. Yes, I also tried executing python -m CGIHTTPServer from command line.. This starts the server successfully, as does my script. :(

Comment: *Aside*: Your script has a bug. You need to print a blank line after the "Content-type" line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out -- I was missing the interpreter line at the beginning of my CGI script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `handler.cgi_directories` to point to the directory containing the cgi script.

Assuming you have stored the file in a folder named `cgi-bin`, the following should do the trick:

`handler.cgi_directories = ['/cgi']`

Comment: Tried changing to '/cgi' as well as '/cgi-bin' to no avail.  :(  Still shows entire script.

Answer (score 0):

You have started your server with a current working directory of `<some-path>\cgi-bin`. This doesn't work very will with CGIHTTPServer. Instead, start it from one level higher (i.e. `<some-path>`).

Also:

- Don't both setting cgi_directories, the default will work.
- Point your browser at `http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/test_cgi.py`

Comment: I did what you said and started this one level higher.  I also navigated to the link you suggested, which didn't give me 404 but it's still printing all the contents of the page.  This is driving me crazy!  Thanks anyway.

Comment: IN addition to those two things, you have to not set `.cgi_directories`.